# HTML scroll bar width

Tags: html, scrollbar, width

I would like to know if there is any scroll bar property in HTML to change the width of the default scroll bar in HTML.

The default size of the scroll bar is 13px. is it possible to increase the the pixel value.

Can anyone help...

Comment: `The default size of the scroll bar is 13px`: no it is not. It depends on the OS.

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is not possible - and if it was, it would be considered by an overwhelming majority of site visitors as "hijacking" their screen: change in scrollbar would make people feel that they had been trapped, and you'd very likely lose every visitor you got, never to return.

I would strongly suggest finding another, more user-friendly strategy. Basically, you need to adapt to the user's needs, not adapt their browser window to your design.

Comment: +1 @Richa for suggesting adapting the web page design to meet the user's need instead of trying to redesign the browser window.

Comment: This is now possible in ie. Chrome. Check the latest GMail interface. It uses custom scrollbar display. And it's native CSS not some javascript plugin.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't change the browser's scrollbar width with HTML or Javascript. You can change the width in windows display parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Webkit browsers can style scrollbars
see [documentation](https://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/)

if you want some crossplatform solution, use javascript.
[SlimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is not HTML ... but it takes the plausible wrapper approach

Check this out>> [Resize Scroll-Bar](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/miscctrl/resizescrollbar.aspx)

Comment: The OP asks specifically for a way in HTML to change the default scrollbars width.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing is in 'internet explorer 10' Scroll comes on as an overlay, It's a cool feature but it can create a mess sometime on any pixel perfect requirement.